# Angular 5 - Extract id from Url

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm new with Angular 5. 
So i'm trying to extract the id from the url so i can send it to a php file and then get back some data from a database.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-a-usuario',
  templateUrl: './a-usuario.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./a-usuario.component.css']
})
export class AUsuarioComponent implements OnInit {
  urlop = 'http://localhost/crudu/mostrarID.php';
  datos: any;
  id: number;


  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
    });
    console.log(this.id);
  }
}
```

I've been trying any solution but it doesn't work (in console log it shows NaN or Undefined)

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {'path': 'admin', component: AdminComponent},
  {'path': 'eUsuario', component: AUsuarioComponent, children: [{
    path: ':id',
      component: AUsuarioComponent
    }]},
  {'path': 'iUsuario', component: IUsuarioComponent},
  {path: '',
    redirectTo: '/',
    pathMatch: 'full'},
  ];
```

Comment: What is the url that you are trying to extract the ID from?

Comment: @hlfrmn eUsuario/id

Answer (score 8):

All you need to do is move the `console.log` inside the `subscribe` to see the value. Trying to access the value outside of the `params.subscribe` will not work, as you have discovered. See below.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.routeListener = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number         
      console.log(this.id);
    });
  }
```

Later inside `ngOnDestroy`, unsubscribe to prevent memory leaks, like:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.routeListener.unsubscribe();
}
```

Any other actions you want to take with what is returned from `params['id']` value would need to happen within the subscribe, too.

Comment: it returned the value of NaN

Comment: Can we have a look at your route definition then?

Comment: Thanks. How about the actual URL that you are using to test this, too?

Comment: There is nothing about it that looks wrong. Are you seeing any error messages in the console? You are using the `+`, too, yes?

Comment: is it possible to get the value stored in this.id outside the route params?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
{'path': 'eUsuario', component: AUsuarioComponent, children: [{
    path: ':id',
      component: AUsuarioComponent
    }]},
```

Instead of having a children route, you can do it directly.

```
 {'path': 'eUsuario/:id', component: AUsuarioComponent},
```